# How to access an Arraylist of another class in java

Tags: java, arrays, class, arraylist, getter

I know that it might be a basic question but the codes that i got for this question does not work on my arraylist. May be someone could help me solve this.I would like to access the arraylist "Connection" of class `Testing1.Java` and use it in another class named `SQL.Java`. My array "Connection" is an object of another array "NamedShape".

Here are my 2 arrayslist:

```
ArrayList<NamedShape> shapes = new ArrayList<NamedShape>();
        ArrayList<Connection> con = new ArrayList<Connection>();

        public class Connection {

            private NamedShape namedShape1;
            private NamedShape namedShape2;

            public Connection(NamedShape namedShape1, NamedShape namedShape2) {
                this.namedShape1 = namedShape1;
                this.namedShape2 = namedShape2;
            }

            public NamedShape getNamedShape1() {
                return namedShape1;
            }

            public NamedShape getNamedShape2() {
                return namedShape2;
            }

            public void setNamedShape1() {
                this.namedShape1 = namedShape1;
            }

            public void setNamedShape2() {
                this.namedShape2 = namedShape2;
            }
        }

        public class NamedShape {

            private String name;
            private Shape shape;

            public NamedShape(String name, Shape shape) {
                this.name = name;
                this.shape = shape;
            }

            public String getName() {
                return name;
            }

            public Shape getShape() {
                return shape;
            }
        }
```

I've put a getConnection Method inside my `Testing1.Java`. Data are inserted correctly inside the Arraylist Connection(I've not put the codes to add the data but data are inserted correctly, that's not the problem)

```
public ArrayList<Connection> getConnection() {
            return con;

        }
```

Here is my Trial `SQL.Java` but it does not recognize the getConnection() method here:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SQL {
    private Testing1 sql;
    public SQL(){
        sql = new Testing1();
        ArrayList<Connection> con = sql.getConnection()

    }

   public static void main(String args[]){
       new Test();


   }
}
```

Can someone please help me out with this?

**Edited**
I've read and followed what you said and now i have this, but i dont know how the main should be. So i have called my class `Testing1.java` to `ERDBUILDER.java`. My ERDBUILDER class allows me to draw shapes and after some processing the shape is stored to an arraylist `Connection`. Then i have my class `SQL.java` where i want to use that arraylist `Connection` by calling the class `SQL.java` from the `ERDBUILDER.java` but i dont want java to open another `ERDBUILDER.java`. I've put `new SQL();` in the main but it's opening another `ERDBUILDER.java` and that's not want i want. can you please suggest something? I might be a basic question but i still can't find a way.

```html
package project;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import project.ERDBUILDER.DrawingBoard.Attribute;
import project.ERDBUILDER.DrawingBoard.Connection;
import project.ERDBUILDER.DrawingBoard.NamedShape;


public class SQL {
    
    private ERDBUILDER sql;
    public SQL(){
        sql = new ERDBUILDER();
    ArrayList<Connection> con = sql.getDrawingBoard().getConnection();
            
        for (int a = 0; a < con.size(); a++) {
                                    NamedShape f = con.get(a).getNamedShape1();
                                    Attribute g = con.get(a).getNamedShape2();
                                    String i = f.getName();
                                    String j = g.getName();

                                    Shape y = f.getShape();
                                    Shape y1 = g.getShape();

                                   
        }
    }
    
   public static void main(String args[]){

       
       
   }
}
```

Comment: Please include the name of the files these code snippets are from, like `SQL.java` and such.

Comment: Can you post the source for your `Testing1` class

Comment: where is Testing1 class

Comment: Incidentally, youre referring to both 'Connection' and 'NamedShape' as arrays. Neither of these is an array. You do have two fields called `shapes` and `con`, but these are ArrayLists of the relevant objects, rather than arrays. To avoid confusion (both for yourself and others) it may be worth correcting this.

Comment: @richzilla It's telling me that i've exceeded the number of character. That's why i did not post the Testing.Java. My Arrays are found inside my Testing1.Java and data are added to the array "Connection" So i just want to access the Array "Connection" from Testing1.Java and use it into Sql.Java

Comment: @Lana, Dont post your code as a comment, edit the question and post it there.

Comment: @richzilla I've edited the question but when i post it here it tell me that body is limited to 30000 characters and i've entered 49000. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @richzilla Please see this  http://pastebin.com/kNNeGwH2

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I've made the modification. Do you have anything that can help me out?

Comment: Figured. Why is `Connection` not its own class in `Connection.java` and `NamedShape` its own class in `NamedShape.java`?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce The Class Connection for the arraylist "Connection" and the class NamedShape for the arraylist "NamedShape" are both found inside the class `Testing1.Java`.

Comment: Ehhh. You shouldn't have those there.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Can you please be clearer?

Comment: Make a new class and new yourclass.java file for those two classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your code as you have posted on pastebin will compile, it is a very unusual pattern.

You have multiple [nested inner classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) within your `Testing1` class.  This is valid Java (i.e. it will compile), but probably isn't necessary for what you want.

#### Quick answer

`getConnection()` isn't available to you in the line

```
ArrayList<Connection> con = sql.getConnection()
```

because your `getConnection()` method is not defined in the class `Testing1`, but rather the inner class of an inner class `Testing1.DrawingBoard.Connection` (line 342 of your code).

#### Fix

1. Make `drawPanel` a member variable of `Testing1` so that you can access it from "outside", either directly by making it a public member, or by adding a `getDrawingBoard()` method that returns it. e.g.

   ```
   public class Testing1 extends JFrame
   {
       private DrawingBoard drawPanel;

       public DrawingBoard getDrawingBoard()
       {
           return drawPanel;
       }

       //...The rest of your existing code except !!!
       // !!! in the Testing1 constructor at line 238 !!!
       // change          final DrawingBoard drawPanel = new DrawingBoard(); to

           drawPanel = new DrawingBoard();

       // ... and the rest of your code...

   }
   ```
2. Move `getConnection()` out of `Connection` - so it is a member of `DrawingBoard` rather than `Connection`.  e.g. (using your existing code as base)

   ```
   //...preceding code before line 324 ...

   public class DrawingBoard extends JComponent
   {

       private static final long serialVersionUID = -4431176095451940075L;

       // ArrayList<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();
       ArrayList<Color> shapeStroke = new ArrayList<Color>();
       ArrayList<Integer> count = new ArrayList<Integer>();
       ArrayList<NamedShape> shapes = new ArrayList<NamedShape>();
       ArrayList<Connection> con = new ArrayList<Connection>();

       public ArrayList<Connection> getConnection()
       {
          return con;
       }

       public class Connection
       {
       // ... rest of your code...
   ```
3. Then, you will be able to do the following in the constructor of `SQL`:

   ```
   public SQL(){
       sql = new Testing1();
       ArrayList<Connection> con = sql.getDrawingBoard().getConnection();
   }
   ```

#### Comment

The pattern you're using is quite hard to follow and maintain.  [More information on when to use nested classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/whentouse.html) is available in the Java tutorials.

In particular - you really don't need `DrawingBoard` to be an inner class of `Testing1` - DrawingBoard could be used in many different applications, so it doesn't fulfill the main criterion

> nested classes enable you to logically group classes *that are only used in one place*

I recommend a refactoring - break out `DrawingBoard` into a new class file `DrawingBoard.java`.  Put it in the same package as `Testing1` then it can be used by `Testing1`.

I'm aware this answer might throw up more questions - if it does - ask a new question about nesting classes versus importing them in your specific case and link to it in the comments...

Comment: @J Richard Snape Thank you for your long and comprehensive response. But i dont want java to open another Testing1 class when i run the .SQL class. Can you please tell me what i should write in the main class? Please see my above edited code.

Comment: Hmm, I can see your edit.  There are a couple of problems here: 1. Your question is "migrating"...  it's now a completely different question to the original, so you should really take your edit and ask a new question, referencing this one.  2. I feel like there's a deeper misunderstanding here - possible an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  I can't see why the code you have is in the Constructor of the `SQL` class. You're hinting that you might be wanting to acess the same `ERDBUILDER` from a number of different classes, but it's not clear...

Comment: In other words - ask a new question, with a bit more context, referencing this one.  Explain exactly what you're trying to do - what is the `SQL` class actually for?  Why not just invoke an `ERDBUILDER`? Is there a bigger problem / code context that you're trying to fit this into?

Comment: @J Richard Snape Ok i will post another new question based on that. In fact what i wanted to do is to create my SQL Statement  in the sql.java but by using the arraylist from the ERDBUILDER.java class.

Comment: By the way - your latest edit to your question means it doesn't make much sense - no one can see the original classes etc now, so my answer would not be understandable to anyone else reading it.  I suggest you roll back to the previous version - particularly as you've now asked [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29204107) to cover your new issue.

Comment: @J Richard Snape I did post the code on pastebin but it's deleted after 3 days.