# How to migrate the data of my arraylist from one class to another class

Tags: java, arraylist, geometry, migration, erd

So i have my an `ERDBUILDER.java` class is a drawing panel which allows me to draw shapes that are stored inside an arraylist `Connection`. I would liked to access this arraylist from another class SQL.java and create my sql statement based on the arraylist. I've tried the codes that follows but i don't know how the main class should be. I've tried to put `new SQL();` in the main class but it's opening another `ERDBUILDER.java` class and that not what i want it to do. 
So how can i run this, how the main class should be?

**EDITED**
Anyone can help?

```html
package project;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import project.ERDBUILDER.DrawingBoard.Attribute;
import project.ERDBUILDER.DrawingBoard.Connection;
import project.ERDBUILDER.DrawingBoard.Connection2;
import project.ERDBUILDER.DrawingBoard.NamedShape;


public class SQL {

public static void main(String args[]){
       ArrayList<Connection> con = new ArrayList<>();
       
        for (int a = 0; a < con.size(); a++) {
                                    NamedShape f = con.get(a).getNamedShape1();
                                    Attribute g = con.get(a).getNamedShape2();
                                    String i = f.getName();
                                    String j = g.getName();

                                    Shape y = f.getShape();
                                    Shape y1 = g.getShape();
                                    System.out.println(i + " AND " + j + " are linked");
                                    
                                    
                                    
                                   
        }
   }    
   
}
```

Comment: You say "but it's opening another ERDBUILDER.java class and that not what i want it to do".  That makes me think you already have another `main` somewhere else that is creating the `ERDBUILDER` object you want.  This makes me think you have a misunderstanding about how objects can access each other.  Each time you run a new `java` process with a `main` - that process is self contained and can't access objects created in another process.  Which class do you want to be "in charge"?  If you want to run `main` in `ERDBUILDER`, then you need to instantiate `SQL` form there, otherwise vice-versa.

Comment: @JRichardSnape My aim is after i've drawn my shape and saved it into the arraylist in `ERDBUILDER.java`, i then launch the `SQL.java` which will analyse the data of the arraylist, without it being shown.  I would like to make the `SQL.java` to run in the background. Just advice me how i should do it?

Comment: @JRichardSnape I have one main in `ERDBUILDER.java` and another main in the `SQL.java`. Well i think that the `SQL.java` should have a main in order to run.

Comment: I think you've got the answer on this and your other question now, right?  You are happy with how it works - you don't need `main()` in both classes?

Comment: @J Richard Snape No i accually need only a main class in my ERDBUILDER.java and not for SQL.java. Hmm for now, its fine with no main in SQL.java

Comment: Great - I'm glad you got the help you needed.  That sounds much more as I would expect.

Comment: @JRichardSnape Thank you so much. That's very kind of you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an instance of the class where you want to create the SQL statement and pass the Connection ArrayList to that class.

```
List<Connection> con = new ArrayList<>();
ERDBuilder x = new ERDBuilder(con);
```

Your ERDBuilder constructor can take a List object and use it to build a SQL statement. Or you can even do this in a method of ERDBuilder. That is your choice.

```
ERDBuilder x = new ERDBuilder();
List<Connection> con = new ArrayList<>();
x.buildSql(con);
```

If you want to do it from main then you have to declare the List as a Class level variable, the same way you have done with the ERDBuilder.

Comment: My aim is after i've drawn my shape and saved it into the arraylist in `ERDBUILDER.java`, i then launch the `SQL.java` which will analyse the data of the arraylist, without it being shown. I would like to make the `SQL.java` to run in the background. Just advice me how i should do it?

Comment: Based on the other comments and this, if you have two main functions, it depends on which class you run using the `java Classname` command. Based on your requirement you only need main in ERDBuilder, then pass the ArrayList to the SQL class. I've explained how to do this above, you only have to change class names as you find appropriate.

Comment: thank you for your reply, and sorry for taking time to understand. Can you tell me what's wrong with my code above? what i should  remove? I will have to remove the main class for sure but what else? I've already passed my Arraylist from the ERDBUILDER class to the SQL class (code sniffet) What i should do next? am confused.

Comment: Don't remove the main class, only the method. You don't need ERDBuilder in the SQL class at all because ERDBuilder is calling SQL, there is no use for ERDBuilder in SQL. Beyond this you will have to do your own research and learn by making some mistakes and asking some more questions as new posts when you get stuck.

Comment: So my SQL class will look like the above edited code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73614/discussion-between-tinker-and-lana).